# Linux command substitution $(cat ...) confusion

Tags: linux, bash, npm

I am configuring NPM to use TLS (this is unrelated).  I have some confusion with how the command substitution in BASH works..

I am issuing the following commands
`npm config set cert "$(cat public.pem)"`

This command works as intended setting the cert field in my .npmrc to the contents of public.pem

Next I issue the command 
`npm config set key "$(cat private.pem)"`

This command fails silently and sets the key field in my .npmrc to empty.

It seems the private key file starts with the standard `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and my public key starts with Bag Attributes.  It seems the file starting with dashes is messing up my command substitution.

Thoughts?

Comment: If you are ever doing `cat` and you are not actually *concatenating* `file` with another file, it is probably a *UUOc* (Unnecessary Use Of `cat`). Redirection as shown in the answer by @choroba is the proper tool for the job and avoids the spawn of a separate subshell.

Comment: `$(...)` is a *command* substitution; process substitution is a different construct.

Comment: Thanks, updated question/title

Comment: Does `cat private.pem` give you any output?

Comment: Yes, ```cat private.pem``` outputs the contents of private.pem

Comment: I can only say to: `It seems the file starting with dashes is messing up my command substitution.` - no, that isn't a problem.

Comment: I just confirmed the real issue is with the ```npm config set``` command

```npm config set key "-----"``` fails ```npm config set key 1234``` works

Comment: Did you try to run `npm config -ddd set key "$(cat private.pem)"` . `-ddd` increases the verbosity.

Comment: try `npm config set key -- "$(<private.pem)"`

Comment: @hek2mgl: I'd say that is almost certainly the problem. My guess is that npm's command processor silently ignores command line flags it doesn't understand.

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config, may be useful.

Comment: @123 Yup that worked like a charm

Comment: If someone wants to make an answer I can accept it...

Answer (score 4):

Where did the `cat` go in the failing command?

```
npm config set key "$(cat private.pem)"
```

Note that you can also use

```
$(< private.pem)
```

which should be a bit faster than calling `cat`.

Comment: The npm config command simply returns with no output.  I am not sure where the cat is going.  I've also tried the ```$(< ...)``` form as well with equal results.  Its specifically when the 'catted' file starts with dashes it seems

Comment: @MatthewKirkley, you misunderstand choroba's answer. Your first (working) command has `$(cat public.pem)` while your second just has `$(private.pem)`. You're missing the `cat` in the second command.

Comment: Whoops, sorry this was a typo on my part.  I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

After a little more research this isn't a problem with command substitution.  `npm config set....` seems to ignore input that starts with dashes.

`npm config set key ----` fails whereas `npm config set key 1234` works

Comment: Also ```npm config set key "----"``` fails

Comment: What about `npm -- config set key ----` or `npm config set key -- ----`?

Comment: @MatthewKirkley: As far as `npm` (or any command line utility) is concerned, there is absolutely no difference between the argument `----` and the argument `"----"`, since bash removes the quotes before passing the argument to the utility.

Comment: @choroba actually yes ```npm -- config set key ----``` did work.  Care to explain why?

Comment: @MatthewKirkley `--` stops it from processing any more flags. If it isn't used then it sees any `-` as a flag.